# Cant build Angular app on Heroku when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace

Tags: java, node.js, angular, spring-boot, heroku

I have a web project consisting of:

- a Spring Boot backend application (Java17),
- an Angular client frontend that communicates with the above backend

The project is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/Thomarkey/hero-matchup-assist) with the following file-structure:

```
|  hero-matchup-assist| 
| -------- | 
|.mvn/wrapper |
| Frontend    |
| src         |
|.gitignore   |
| README.md   |
| app.json    |
| mvnw        |
| mvnw.cmd    |
| pom.xml     |
| static.json |
| system.properties |
```

This is my `package.json` located at `\dotaApplicationTool\Frontend`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.15.0",
    "npm": "9.6.2"
  }
}
```

This is my `server.js` located at `\dotaApplicationTool\Frontend`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./dist/'));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: 'dist/' });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

This is my `angular.json` located at `\dotaApplicationTool\Frontend`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

When I deploy this project to Heroku, my mainpage is getting a 404, if I hard navigate to a known (api) end-point I do however get the 204 json response, but nothing from the frontend.

Locally everything works fine on port 4200 (`ng serve`) but I have the same problems when I run it with the `ng build` command and go look on 8080.

This is my Heroku log

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/java
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 17... done
-----> Executing Maven
       $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] ------------------< com.example:dotaApplicationTool >-------------------
       [INFO] Building heroMatchupAssistant 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ dotaApplicationTool ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.5.0:list (default-cli) @ dotaApplicationTool ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ 
       dotaApplicationTool ---
       [INFO] Copying 1 resource from src/main/resources to target/classes
       [INFO] Copying 1 resource from src/main/resources to target/classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ dotaApplicationTool 
       ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
       [INFO] Compiling 4 source files with javac [debug release 17] to target/classes
       [INFO] 
       /tmp/build_6e5a0402/src/main/java/com/example/dotaApplicationTool/HeroDisplay.java: 
       Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
       [INFO] 
       /tmp/build_6e5a0402/src/main/java/com/example/dotaApplicationTool/HeroDisplay.java: 
       Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ 
       dotaApplicationTool ---
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_6e5a0402/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 
       dotaApplicationTool ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
       [INFO] Compiling 1 source file with javac [debug release 17] to target/test-classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) @ dotaApplicationTool ---
       [INFO] Tests are skipped.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ dotaApplicationTool ---
       [INFO] Building jar: /tmp/build_6e5a0402/target/dotaApplicationTool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.0:repackage (repackage) @ dotaApplicationTool - 
       --
       [INFO] Replacing main artifact /tmp/build_6e5a0402/target/dotaApplicationTool-0.0.1- 
       SNAPSHOT.jar with repackaged archive, adding nested dependencies in BOOT-INF/.
       [INFO] The original artifact has been renamed to 
       /tmp/build_6e5a0402/target/dotaApplicationTool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ dotaApplicationTool - 
       --
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_6e5a0402/pom.xml to 
       /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/example/dotaApplicationTool/0.0.1- 
       SNAPSHOT/dotaApplicationTool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_6e5a0402/target/dotaApplicationTool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to 
       /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/example/dotaApplicationTool/0.0.1- 
       SNAPSHOT/dotaApplicationTool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  4.483 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-19T11:43:54Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       -----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
       -----> Compressing...
       Done: 109.6M
       -----> Launching...
       Released v15
       https://hero-matchup-assistant-25269114e6bf.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

So I think all I see here is the Java backend (mvn) config and nothing from the Angular frontend?

Also fyi my /dist folder is also located at `\dotaApplicationTool\Frontend` and is not included in the `.gitignore` file.

Please let me know if I have to provide other code snippets.

--UPDATE--

So I added the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack to my app in the Heroku Settings tab for this project.

I also had to move the  `package.json` to the main root folder (under the hero-mathup-assist)

Now I have a build problem, here is my Heroku log for this part:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  18.15.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   9.6.2
       
       Resolving node version 18.15.0...
       Downloading and installing node 18.15.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 9.6.2 (replacing 9.5.0)...
       npm 9.6.2 installed
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       
       added 931 packages, and audited 932 packages in 23s
       
       105 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       npm notice 
       npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.6.2 -> 9.7.1
       npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.7.1>
       npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.7.1` to update!
       npm notice 
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > frontend@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild
       > ng build
       
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: I understand the error because its trying to run a ng command when not in the angular root folder, but I moved it to the project root folder just because otherwise I get this error in the heroku build:


`!  A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of the directory structure.
If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this file is present at the top level directory.`

Answer (score 0):

I also deploy to heroku. Just upgraded an Angular 9 web app to 15. Chose to just move the code rather than step build versions. Got an application error because I forgot that heroku liked the web launch from express. I installed express.

package.json...

```
'
 {
  "name": "nomadic-brian-website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
       "ng": "ng",
  "start": "node server.js",
  "build": "ng build",
  "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
  "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
  "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
  "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
  "express": "^4.18.2",
  "ng-image-slider": "^7.0.0",
  "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
   "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.1",
   "@angular/cli": "~15.0.1",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
   "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
   "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
   "karma": "~6.4.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
   "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
   "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
   "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  },
  "description": "App for NFL Colts stats with Python SVGs and Angular 
   Material.",
  "author": "Brian Quinn",
  "email": "bofcarbon1@gmail.com",
  "url": "https://nomadic-brian-site.herokuapp.com/",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/bofcarbon1/nomadic-brian-website.git"
  }
 }

'
```

server.js...

```
'
 const path = require("path");
 const express = require("express");
 const app = express();

 // Serve static files....
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist/nomadic-brian-website"));

 // Send all requests to index.html
 app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/nomadic-brian- 
 website/index.html"));
 });

 // Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
 app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4200);

'
```